# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working in Apache2.4

Tags: php, apache, header, apache2.4

I have just upgraded to v2.4 from 2.2 in Apache on my local Windows 7 Machine, I am running apach2.4 x64 and php 5.5 x64.

In my **Vhost** I have:

```
<Directory /var/www/somedomain.co.uk/docroot>
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{HTTP_ORIGIN}e" env=HTTP_ORIGIN 
</Directory>
```

My apache `httpd.config`

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule php5_module "C:\php\php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:\php\"
```

My `javaScript` code hasn't changed at all. However now when I try to ajax to this domain from another I get a 200 error:

```
POST http://somedomain.local/app/users/login 200 OK 2,53s     jquery.min.js (line 6)
Sorry Login Failed: 200                                       global.js (line 34)
```

I can also post to `http://somedomain.local/app/use\rs/login` from this domain in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had nothing to do with Apache2.4.

Since my upgrade I had no turned on `error_reporting` and thus, no errors were being displayed.

Turned them on, fixed the error I needed and the server started up.